# Python Classes Global NameError

Tags: python, class, nameerror

I am learning classes and I wrote a simple program to understand them better. The program is basically a class to open files. However, I keep getting:

> NameError: global name 'book' is not defined

I thought that initializing `self.book = book` in the `__init__` method would enable me to pass it to the next method. But this isn't working. How can I pass `self.book` on to the `open_file` method?

```
class AnalyzeBook(object):
    def __init__(self, filename, book):
        self.filename = filename
        self.book = book

    def open_file(self, filename, book):

        with open(self.filename) as f:
            self.book = f.readlines()

            return self.book


book_analysis = AnalyzeBook('lordoftherings.txt', book=None)
book_analysis.open_file('lordoftherings.txt', book=None)
```

**Edit:** Updated my code to add book to `__init__` and `book=None` and that worked.

Comment: So what should `self.book` be set *to*. You only gave the class a filename.

Comment: Also, copy and paste your code from your editor, don't re-type it. Those fancy quotes on the last-but-one line would normally cause a syntax error, so some 'smart' text auto-improvement somewhere inserted those as you typed.

Comment: You can also do self.book = None in init

Comment: That depends. Does every instance start with a different value for `self.book`? If not, you can just hardcode the value: `self.book = 'tree'` and not make it an argument to the `__init__` function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add variable book to your class constructor.

```
def __init__(self, filename, book):
    self.filename = filename
    self.book = book
```

When you initialize an instance of the AnalyzeBook class, also supply book variable.